# Cisco ASA 5505 L2L vpn issue

Tags: networking, cisco, cisco-asa, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn

this is my setup

[image: Current Setup]

I already have a working L2L VPN between the sites

I added the 10.10.0.0/24 to the object-groups that defines the internal network on the 1615 ASA
And as a remote subnet on the 1604 ASA

im not seing the 10.10.0.1 from the 1604 side, Also i added the sysopt connection permit-vpn on both sides

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the tunnel policy access list look like? Does the new subnet show up in `show crypto ipsec sa`'s remote and local networks?

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply 
Subnet is not showing up under the Ipsec SA
Here is the config files for both sides 
1615  - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5cpmzeafnp0bgny/1615.txt
1614  - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/bc8cexsq3hlx9la/1604.txt

Comment: So the 1604 location has a DHCP address, that's why it's dynamic on the 1615 side?  The `outside_1_cryptomap_1604` ACL looks unused.  Can you run `packet-tracer input inside tcp 192.168.5.1 1024 10.10.0.1 5061 detailed` on the 1604 side and provide the output?

Comment: I initiated a ping to 10.10.0.1 and ran the packet trace and it passes through | results - 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/hd99w9gvehlaa5h/packetTrace_1604.txt | Ipsec sa - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ybwhcmgufvclyug/1604_ipsecSA.txt?dl=0

Comment: Packet trace from the 1615 side - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/r2wnid5orlyrs6p/packetTrace_1615.txt

Comment: Those look good - what's the ipsec sa list look like on the 1615 side? (the packet trace on the 1615 side showing deny is no concern, as there's no way of telling packet-tracer "evaluate as if this would be coming through this VPN tunnel"; it'll always deny that traffic coming from the internet)

Comment: 1615 IPsec SA - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mx8xtb9k80dqf71/1615_IpsecSA.txt | BTW thanks a lot for the checking on this

Comment: Hmm, so the ipsec sa won't build on the 1615 side - try just clearing the tunnels to 1604 altogether and letting them rebuild? Then check if the ipsec sa output on 1615 has changed at all right after a ping attempt from 1604. Might be something odd going on with the dynamic map..

Comment: Progress..I cleared the SA and let the ASA rebuild the sa. now the 10.10.0.0/24 shows up as a local ident | 1615_ipsecSA_output - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/dfy8baminvr1eve/1615_IpsecSA_2.txt | unfortunatly still cant get to 10.10.0.1 from the 1604 side

Comment: I have the voice VLAN setup as a interface on the 1615 ASA. do i need a no nat statement for that voice interface ?

Answer (score 1):

You got it, the missing nat rule is exactly the problem - I saw that the NO-NAT ACL had 10.10.0.0/24 to 192.168.5.0/24 allowed, but I missed that you only had a `nat 0` setup for the inside interface, where the voice traffic isn't going.

Add a `nat (voiceVlan) 0 access-list NO-NAT` configuration to allow the traffic through.